# How to add the header in the request options in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, observable

I am trying to add the requestoption and header but it is throwing the following error

```
    src/app/pages/ldapp/ldapp.service.ts(72,5): error TS2322: Type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to type 'Headers'.
    Property 'forEach' is missing in type 'HttpHeaders'.
    src/app/pages/ldapp/ldapp.service.ts(74,31): error TS2345: Argument of type 'RequestOptions' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
    Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
        Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
        Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
            Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'
```

Following is my code

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()

export class LDappService {

    private headers: HttpHeaders;


    constructor(){
        this.headers = new HttpHeaders();
    }

    private addAuthorizationHeader = () => {
    this.headers.delete('Authorization');
    this.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.appState.get('_a_token'));
    }

    getladderRequest(gcid, callId, protocol, epoch) {
        this.addAuthorizationHeader();
        const url = this.baseApiUrl 
        this.urlParams = new URLSearchParams();
        this.urlParams.set('callID', callId);
        this.urlParams.set('protocol', 'SIP');    
        if (gcid != "") {
            this.urlParams.set('gcid', gcid);
        }    
        this.urlParams.set('pkey', epoch);    
        this.requestOptions.search = this.urlParams;
        this.requestOptions.headers = this.headers;

        return this.http.get(url, this.requestOptions).pipe(map(
            res => {
                return res;
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that append creates new instance so Y=X.append()... keeps X unmodified and Y will have x+appended header.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpHeaders.append(...)` creates a new `HttpHeaders` object with the new header added to it, it doesn't alter your current `HttpHeaders` object instance.

This should solve your issue:

```
this.headers = this.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.appState.get('_a_token'));
```

Keep in mind that headers are immutable, meaning that any modification done to them returns a new instance, it wont mutate the object itself.